# Difference between silverlight tools, silverlight SDK, silverlight toolkit, silverlight development tools

Tags: silverlight

I'm installing a programming environment for Silverlight and trying to straighten out what needs to be installed, feedback is appreciated:

1. At http://silverlight.net/GetStarted, point number one allows you to install "**Silverlight Tools** for Visual Studio 2008 SP1". The book (Silverlight 2, Wiley) that I am reading seems to refer to this as the "**Silverlight SDK**".
2. Also at http://silverlight.net/GetStarted, point number four allows you to install "**Silverlight Toolkit**" which my book refers to as "**Silverlight Development Tools**".

So the way I understand it, there are only 2 things to install, the names just seem to not be consistent. Or are there really 3 or 4 different things to install?

Comment: Silverlight 5... same confusion still.

Comment: Confused about SL 3 and VS 2008, SL 4 and VS 2010, SL5 and VS 2010-VS 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct:
 - the first one refers to the actual SDK (along with documentation, Visual Studio templates and examples). You must install this one in order to develop a Silverlight 2 web application.
 - the second one is a collection of controls and classes already coded and ready to be used in any Silverlight 2 web application. This one is not required but you can find it very useful since it's a community project, constantly mantained and updated with new features.

Comment: I have installed Silverlight3_tools and Silverlight_sdk and still unable to find DockPanel in the toolbox. Both the installers installed without asking for a save location. How do I find the reference now?

Comment: @user20358 try looking in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Toolkit\Nov09\Bin` it was my default install location

Comment: @user20358 differents installers about Silverlight3_tools and Silverlight_sdk ?